# How to Stop a Sitecore resource group in Azure PaaS

Tags: azure, paas

Is there any way to disable or stop the whole resource group temporary? We can stop the individual’s WebApps within the resource group. The whole idea is to save the cost of the services if I am not using the environment at all.

In the Sitecore 9 XP single installation there are total 21 items installed including databases, App service etc..

It would be great if I can switch off/On my Sitecore environment  from resource group level.

Any thoughts/Ideas?

Comment: Can you try in this way using powershel : Get-AzureRmResourceGroup <group name> | Stop-AzureRmVM -Force

Comment: will it work for application insight as well, and all other resource type?

Comment: look at this question, it is for similar subject. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628320/stopping-or-disabling-a-resource-group-in-azure

Answer (score 2):

This is more of an Azure feature question.

You can not stop an Azure Resource Group, because technically the resource group isn't running, but there is also no feature to disable or pause all of the resources in Azure currently.

Like you said, you can pause the Web App roles, however, pausing them, does not remove all the costs of running those web app roles.

There is an open suggestion here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/17670613-hibernate-pause-a-resource-group-or-subscription related to adding in this support.

My suggestion for now, until Microsoft adds this feature (if they ever do), is to just delete the resource group.  If you used an ARM Template to create the resource group and the roles within that, than use the same ARM Template to recreate it.  If you didn't use an ARM template, than I would recommend using one of the existing Sitecore ARM templates and/or modifying it to meet your needs.